# Django raises the exception for error wont override for HttpResponse

Tags: python, django

I am using the Django to create my custom error page handler for 400, 403, 404 ,500. But for some reason, when the page return HttpResponse error, it wont direct me to my django custom error template page, instead of, it shows this. This django can find the url and go in the view function, but we return HttpResponse 404 it is not found. [image: Error in HttpResponse404]
For example, http://127.0.0.1:8000/404/ , this will go to the customize page because Django cannot find this url in our project

[image: error page with own template]

```
### views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
def page_not_found_view(request, exception):

   return render(request, 'error.html',status = 404,context = {
        'status_code' : 404,
        'message' : "The page you were looking for doesn't exist anymore.",
        'title' : "Page Not Found"
    })

def internal_server_error_view(request,  *args, **argv):

   return render(request, 'error.html',status = 500,context = {
        'status_code' : 500,
        'message' : "500 Internal Server Error.",
        'title' : "Internal Server Error"
    })

def forbidden_error_view(request, exception):

   return render(request, 'error.html',status = 403,context = {
        'status_code' : 403,
        'message' : "403 Forbidden Error.",
        'title' : "Forbidden Error"
    })

def bad_request_error_view(request, exception):

   return render(request, 'error.html',status = 400,context = {
        'status_code' : 400,
        'message' : "400 Bad Request Error.",
        'title' : "Bad Request"
    })
    
### urls.py
hanlder400 = "gotani.views.bad_request_error_view"
handler404 = "gotani.views.page_not_found_view"
handler403 = "gotani.views.forbidden_error_view"
handler500 = "gotani.views.internal_server_error_view"
```

Comment: can you use other browser or open private mode and try again??

Comment: yes, I do but the page return in the HttpResponse(404) which isn't called by the error handler functions in views.py

Comment: In your view, you have to `raise Http404` for the 404 page to be used

Comment: where do i put the `raise Http404` ? in the view function?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> For convenience, and because it’s a good idea to have a consistent 404 error page across your site, Django provides an Http404 exception. If you raise Http404 at any point in a view function, Django will catch it and return the standard error page for your application, along with an HTTP error code 404.

Instead of `render`, use `raise`. You can use `raise` with different types of errors and it will fetch the correct error page.

```
raise Http404("Poll does not exist")
```

**Keep in mind that there's no need to use external packages for this.** You can simply add a `404.html` page at template root level and Django will automatically serve it when it encounters a `404 error`. The same is true for other error codes.